# Maybe [SO] should consider improving SO's UX a little bit

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, user-experience, stack-exchange

Stack Overflow's user interface is still a confusing mess. Users don't know where to ask questions. It has turned the experienced members of the community into garbage collectors.

From [How to install Alpine Linux on disk on a VPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118876/how-to-install-alpine-linux-on-disk-on-a-vps#comment104473137_59118876):

> ... could you tell me where is this specified? maybe I missed
>   something. When I go to the homepage or even in the very "ask
>   question" page I cannot see such straightforward guidance on where to
>   ask for what. I'll gladly ask in the cited networks, but maybe SO
>   moderators (like you?) should consider improving SO's UX a little bit?
>   For instance, in the "ask question" page maybe SO could simply put a
>   "category" or better: just infer the category based on the tags we
>   put. This question has Linux + Alpine tag: do you see any fit for SO
>   to just warn me "hey, these tags are for stackexchange"?

Comment: That question is never going to be on-topic for Stack Overflow, so I’m not sure what we can possibly do to improve the UX surrounding it. The problem is not that they merely got the tags wrong.

Comment: What part of that question is programming-related? The ask question page (at least for me) has a call-out labeled “Have a non-programming question?” Which gives several outlets for these kinds of questions. There is no magical UX fairy dust you can sprinkle on the web site that will make users like this one post their question on the correct site. They made a mistake; these days, they blame the UX, 20 years ago they would’ve blamed a lack of signs while standing in front of exactly the sign they were describing. Admit their error and apologize? Sounds positively quaint.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: But there could be a single Stack Exchange site where part of the process would be the transfer to the correct site (or closed as not appropriate on any).

Comment: @PeterMortensen who would decide on the correct site and do the transferring?

Comment: All the people pointing out that the question provided as an example is off-topic. Pretty funny. Whether the example question is on- or off-topic is irrelevant: the UX of SO is total trash. It is from the dark ages of the internet when using JavaScript on webpages was frowned upon. It doesn't even have a dark mode and you have to opt-in to remove the pointless side-bar. SO is an important resource and it is dying. FIX IT.

Comment: @Ben Interesting perspective, considering that Stack Overflow uses JavaScript *extensively* (probably relying on it *too* heavily, from my point of view) and that the best, most popular sites on the Internet don't have a "dark mode", either. (Themes are a browser/OS feature.) I agree that the side bar is pointless, and that the sticky top-bar is an anti-pattern (which can also only be fixed by creating an account), but these are relatively minor complaints, and the design is largely driven not by designers but by bean-counters (e.g., the sidebar is an advertising mechanism for Teams).

Comment: @Ben no.  Asserting that a question is off-topic for a site you know well requires little effort from a curator.  Deciding on an appropriate site is non-trivial, and the only user qualified, and responsible, to choose is the OP.

Comment: @Ben SO is indeed an important resource. Which is why I am happy they use time on issues less trivial than having a dark mode....

Comment: Not exactly clear what this question tries to do: clearly it is not a "bug" as this is current behavior and it is "by design", there is nothing for community to do  as this is potentially  some hidden request to SE as company to do some UI changes (also currently blog posts clearly state that meta is not a place for such request).

Comment: @Alexei - "clearly" it is a chronic bug. It should have been fixed years ago during the execution of a development life cycle. In particular, phase 5: documentation and feedback. Once the loop occurred, phase 2: analysis will uncover the root cause. And regarding where to report bugs, please see [Where can I post feedback about something that’s broken or an idea I have for a feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/give-feedback) in the Help Center.

Comment: @Patrice in these dark times a dark mode seems appropriate ...